# Message passing between background threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

**Background**

My application creates a number of background threads to parallelise a complex iterative task. At the end of each iteration I need all the background threads to share data, synchronise and iterate again. I have implemented this by creating a set of `HandlerThread` and then passing my iteration as a `Runnable`. The message passing is performed at the end of each iteration *inside* the `run()` (part of the problem).

**Problem**

The [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) offers guidance on how to attach a Handler to the UI thread to process incoming messages from background tasks. As the UI thread ought to be free from load to respond to touch events etc. it calls `handleMessage()` pretty much as soon as a message arrives in the queue as it is not doing anything else. In my problem, the background threads are still processing my `Runnable` (i.e. it is running the `run()` code) and hence, although messages are being posted to the queue, they are not getting handled by the receiving threads as they are busy doing `run()`.

**Questions**

Coming from using [MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) in C++, my concept of message sending and receiving feels like there should be a way to block a thread until it grabs and processes a message from the queue. `wait()` would suspend the whole thread which wouldn't help.

1. Is there a way to achieve this in my current implementation framework?

I have used `AsyncTask` before for this type of work but found synchronising these tasks messy with `static AtomicIntegers` and ended up having a lot of static variables to ensure each task could access things without the use of handlers.

2. Has anyone achieved similar background communication and synchronisation with an array of `AsyncTask`?

**Model Code**

MainActivity.java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static boolean run_flag = false;
public static final int numThreads = 2;
static Vector<Handler> handlerArray = new Vector<>(numThreads);
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);


    // Create barrier and start each thread
    run_flag = true;
    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(numThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        HandlerThread t = new HandlerThread("Thread" + i);
        t.start();

        // Create handler, attach to the new thread, store reference in static array
        handlerArray.addElement( new Handler(t.getLooper()) {

            // Define handler for message processing
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message incoming_msg) {

                // Do something with the passed value
                Log.d("Handler " + android.os.Process.myTid(), "Handling message");

            }
        } );

        // Pass runnable to this new thread
        handlerArray.get(i).post( new MyRunnable(i, barrier) );

    }

    // Attach listener to button
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Stop the runnables
            run_flag = false;
        }
    });

}
}
```

MyRunnable.java is:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

// Fields
int value;
CyclicBarrier barrier;
int id;

// Constructor
public MyRunnable(int id, CyclicBarrier barrier) {

    this.value = 0;
    this.barrier = barrier;
    this.id = id;

}

// Inner container class
class MyContainer {
    int messagevalue;

    public MyContainer(int msg_value) {

        this.messagevalue = msg_value;
    }
}


@Override
public void run( ) {

    Log.d("Runnable " + android.os.Process.myTid(), "Starting Runnable");

    while (MainActivity.run_flag) {

        // Do something //
        value++;

        // Create and send a message to other thread
        int destination = (id + 1 % MainActivity.numThreads) - 1;
        Message msg =
                MainActivity.handlerArray.get(destination).obtainMessage();
        msg.obj = new MyContainer(10*value);
        MainActivity.handlerArray.get(destination).sendMessage(msg);


        // Synchronise before begin next iteration
        try {
            barrier.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Broken or interrupted exceptions handled here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    Log.d("Runnable " + android.os.Process.myTid(), "Stopping Runnable, Value = " + value);


}

}
```

Comment: While waiting for suggestions I have experimented with using a 3rd thread to manage the posting of `Runnables` to the worker threads and enforce synchronisation through barriers in message handler. It works but doesn't seem like a neat solution.